# Change the TextView value based on other TextView

Tags: java, android

I was trying to create a little game, and it works like this: When you achieve 10 points, the next step is to achieve 20 points, but I cannot change the textview variable.

```
if(tv_score.getText().toString().equals("Score: "+10)){
            tv_nextStep.setText("Next step: " + 10);
        }
if(tv_score.getText().toString().equals("Score: "+20)){
                tv_nextStep.setText("Next step: " + 30);
            }
```

I was trying to get the score from the textview, and based on that, change the next step textview, but the value is always 0 (the default value).

the score is like this: When I click the button, the score goes to the textview (this part is working)

```
score = score + 1;
        tv_score.setText("Score: " + score);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by 'but the value is always 0 (the default value)' , is it the score you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, the default value for the score is 0

Comment: The score is obviously changing as you mentioned , I think better would be to implement as @ZeroOne suggested as below

Comment: yes, I did that, but if you have 2 buttons, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing this is what you want?

```
int score = 0;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
       score = score + 1;
       tv_score.setText("Score: " + score);

       if(score == 10){
            tv_nextStep.setText("Next step: " + 10);
       }
       if(score == 20){
            tv_nextStep.setText("Next step: " + 30);
       }
    }
});
```